# How to cast Dictionary<string,MyClass> to Dictionary<string,object>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, dictionary, casting

I have the following classes:

```
public class BagA : Dictionary<string, BagB>
{}
public class BagB : Dictionary<string, object>
{}
```

Now, through reflection I'm creating an object of type BagB which I'm
trying to add to an object I created of type BagA:

```
object MyBagA // Created through reflection
object MyBagB // Created through reflection

((Dictionary<string,object>)MyBagA).Add("123",MyBagB);  //This doesnt work
```

Gives me the following error: Unable to cast object of type 'BagA' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'.

Why can't I cast a `Dictionary<string, BagB>` to `Dictionary<string, object>`?
Which is the best way to add my Item based on this scenario? perhaps Anonymous methods..?

Notice that I would prefer not having to modify my classes BagA and BagB...

Thanks!

Comment: Why not cast MyBagB to bag B instead of casting the dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you used reflection to create your objects, it's only fair that you need to continue using it to call their methods:

```
var addMethod = typeof(BagA).GetMethod("Add", new[] {typeof(string), typeof(BagB)});
addMethod.Invoke(MyBagA, new object[] {"123", MyBagB});
```

Comment: That is what I ended up doing and works fine although its a little more elaborated. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do a cast here because `Dictionary<string, BagB>` and `Dictionary<string, object>` are different incompatible types.  Instead of casting the `Dictionary` why not cast the values instead?

```
MyBagA.Add("123", (BagB)MyBagB);
```

If it were legal to cast the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` then then very evil things could happen.  Consider

```
Dictionary<string, BagB> map1 = ...;
Dictionary<string, object> map2 = SomeEvilCast(map1);
map2["foo"] = new object();
```

What would now happen if I tried to access `map1["foo"]`?  The type of the value is `object` but it's statically typed to `BagB`.

Comment: Good observation @JaredPar, makes perfect sense

Answer (score 2):

This is fundamentally impossible.

Had you been able to do that, you would be able to add arbitrary other types.

You need to call the method using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly cast or convert an instance of a generic type to an instance of the type with different generic parameters, UNLESS the generic type is specifically defined as covariant (able to be treated as a generic of a base class of the actual declared generic type) on that particular generic type parameter, AND you are attempting to cast the type to a generic of a base class of its actual type. For instance, an `IEnumerable<string>` can be treated as an `IEnumerable<object>` because string derives from object. It cannot be treated as an `IEnumerable<char>` even if all the strings only have one character, because String does not derive from Char.

Covariance is definable in C# 4.0 using the `out` keyword on the generic parameter, but to my knowledge, unlike IEnumerable, the generic IDictionary interface is not specified as covariant. In addition, even though a Dictionary is IEnumerable, it's an IEnumerable of the generic key/value pairs, and generic KVPs are not covariant, so you cannot treat the KVP's generic parameters as base types.

What you can do is create a new Dictionary of the new type and transfer all the values from the old one. If those values are reference types, changing a sub-value of one Dictionary's reference-typed Value will change it in the corresponding Value of the other Dictionary (unless you change the reference itself, by assigning a new instance of MyClass to the Value for that key).

A little Linq makes this one pretty easy:

```
Dictionary<string, MyClass> MyStronglyTypedDictionary = 
   new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
//populate MyStronglyTypedDictionary

//a Dictionary<T1, T2> is an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T1, T2>>
//so most basic Linq methods will work
Dictionary<string, object> MyGeneralDictionary = 
   MyStronglyTypedDictionary.ToDictionary(kvp=>kvp.Key, kvp=>(object)(kvp.Value));

...

//Now, changing a MyClass instance's data values in one Dictionary will 
//update the other Dictionary
((MyClass)MyGeneralDictionary["Key1"]).MyProperty = "Something else";

if(MyStronglyTypedDictionary["Key1"].MyProperty == "Something else")
{
    //the above is true; this code will execute
}

//But changing a MyClass reference to a completely new instance will
//NOT change the original Dictionary
MyGeneralDictionary["Key1"] = new MyClass{MyProperty = "Something new"};

if(MyStronglyTypedDictionary["Key1"].MyProperty == "Something else")
{
    //the above is STILL true even though the instance under this key in the 
    //other Dictionary has a different value for the property, because
    //the other dictionary now points to a different instance of MyClass;
    //the instance that this Dictionary refers to never changed.
}
```

Comment: This is not correct.  A `List<string>` cannot be treated as a `List<object>` because you cannot call `stringList.Add(fileInfo);`.  A `List<string>` (or any `IEnumerable<string>`) can be treated as an `IEnumerable<object>`.  So two problems with the answer as it is: (1) `List<T>` is not declared covariant.  (2) Classes can never be declared co- or contravariant, only interfaces and delegates.

Comment: I'll add to what @phoog said. Suppose you have types `V1 : V2 : V3`, forming an inheritance chain. You can't weaken a `List<V2>` to a `List<V3>` by wrapping it because the latter would then ultimately end up sending `V3` types down to the `V2` list when you try to add to it. Nor can you strengthen a `List<V2>` to a `List<V3>` because the get method on the former is not guaranteed to give you `V3` typed objects. However, if you separate the list interface into the getters & the setters, I believe then you can weaken/strengthen the types, respectively.